# How to set and get cookies in EE 3?

Tags: cookies

I have found how to set/get browser cookies using older versions of EE (1&2) and can obviously do this also in EE 3 using legacy functions/libraries.

How would I do this in EE 3 NOT using legacy functions?

I would like to store a shopping chart for not yet registed users.

Answer (score 1):

EE3 still uses the [legacy Input library](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/libraries/input.html#setting-and-deleting-cookies) internally, so the same methods apply.

```
ee()->input->cookie();
ee()->input->set_cookie();
ee()->input->delete_cookie();
```

Or, use the [Cookie Helper](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/helpers/cookie_helper.html).

The one new method you can use for *getting* a cookie is the Request service.

```
ee('Request')->cookie($name, $default_value);
```